# Why is my query called over and over using useLazyQuery? Apollo Hooks

Tags: react-apollo, react-apollo-hooks

I am using the `useLazyQuery` hook from Apollo and get in an infinite loop.  Here is my component:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { useLazyQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks"

import GENERATE_EFT_REFERENCE_NUMBER from "./graphql/generate-eft-reference-number.graphql"

let Link = styled.a`
  color: ${props => props.theme.color.turquoise500};
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
`


const GenerateEftReferenceLink = ({
  externalAccountId,
  financialMethodId,
  internalAccountId,
  highestReferenceNumber,
  methodId,
  updateMethod
}) => {
  const [generateEftReference = {}, { called, loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(
    GENERATE_EFT_REFERENCE_NUMBER,
    {
      variables: {
        externalAccountId,
        financialMethodId,
        internalAccountId,
        highestReferenceNumber
      },
      onCompleted: ({ generateEftReferenceNumber: reconciliationSerialNumber }) => {
        updateMethod({ reconciliationSerialNumber }, methodId)
      }
    }
  )

  return <Link onClick={generateEftReference}>Click Me</Link>
}

export default GenerateEftReferenceLink
```

In the `onCompleted` option, I take the result and use a callback (`updateMethod`) to update my object.

The issue I am having is that the query gets called over and over.  I hit the `onCompleted` each time, which calls `updateMethod` and I stay in this infinite loop.  The `onClick` is only being called when the `Link` is clicked (I verified that by putting a `debugger` in the `onClick`), so this must be something to do with the `useLazyQuery` hook.

I fixed this by changing to use the `ApolloConsumer` component, but I want to understand why I get in this state with the hook.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in Apollo, they fixed it in @apollo/react-hooks v3.1.3
[See this](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/3690)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with `useQuery` hook, and I was not able to update the library to the latest version, which will cause some side effects in my project, so I solved it in this way, mine while I update the lib.

`onCompleted: useCallback(() => {//your code}`